# How do I use SQL statements for BETWEEN?

Tags: sql, .net, textbox, between

Please see my pictures. I have store.And i want search (filter) in my store . "Hrubka is in English "Thickness"

These code works for me:

```
            using (SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter(" select * from tab_sklad where SMENA LIKE '%" + txt_smena_sklad_filter.Text +
                "%'and DATUM LIKE '%" + txt_datum_sklad_filter.Text +
                "%'and DODAVATEL LIKE '%" + cmb_firma_sklad_filter.Text +
                "%'and CISLO_PALETY LIKE '%" + txt_paleta_sklad_filter.Text +
                "%'and HRUBKA LIKE '%" + txt_hrubka_sklad_filter.Text +
                "%'and KVALITA LIKE '%" + cmb_kvalita_sklad_filter.Text +
                "%'and DRUH LIKE '%" + cmb_druh_sklad_filter.Text +

                "%'", cn))
            {
```

but I want add search "from to" : column "H"

SAMPLE:

between

from 40 to 50
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1FLg.png)

[printscreen mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h98am.png)

[image][image]

Comment: "does not work" Is not a problem description. Does it trow an error? What is the error message? Does it return unexpected results? What do you expect? What does it actually return? Show some sample data.

Comment: Môj príkaz SQL je zle, chcem ciciak dáta v údajová mriežka textboxs. Please see my pictures.

Answer (score 3):

In general, when you are constructing queries, you should print out the query.  Then the error is probably obvious.

Before even continuing, I also want to point out that you should be using parameterized queries.  That has nothing to do with your issue, but it is the best practice.

Your last condition is:

```
HRUBKA BETWEEN VALUES'%" + txt_sklad_od.Text "%'AND'% " + txt_sklad_do.Text+"'"
```

You are using percent signs in the comparison values and have the keyword `VALUES` in an inappropriate place.  I suspect that you intend some sort of wild-carding, such as with `LIKE`, but this is not how that works.  For your current query structure you would remove the percent signs:

```
HRUBKA BETWEEN '" + txt_sklad_od.Text "' AND '" + txt_sklad_do.Text+"'"
```

Comment: In the first place what's the use of wildcarding using BETWEEN? Sounds omnious to me, isn't it only me?

More, using a TextBox like that... SQL Injection spotted!

Comment: I added images.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Gordon Linoff answer I wish to add some more edits to your code.

Your code isn't "injection safe" ([check SQL Injection here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)). I also don't understand the use of `BETWEEN` here... Is `HRUBKA` a number field? (Int, float, numeric, etc)

If `HRUBKA` is a number it would be like:

```
double sklad_od = 0, sklad_do = 0;
using (SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter(" select * from tab_sklad "
        "where SMENA LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_smena_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (txt_smena_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " and DATUM LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_datum_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (txt_datum_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " and DODAVATEL LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_firma_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (cmb_firma_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " and CISLO_PALETY LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_paleta_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (txt_paleta_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " and HRUBKA LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_hrubka_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (txt_hrubka_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " and KVALITA LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_kvalita_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (cmb_kvalita_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") + 
         " and DRUH LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_druh_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (cmb_druh_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         (double.TryParse(txt_sklad_od.Text, out sklad_od) && double.TryParse(txt_sklad_do.Text, out sklad_do) ? (" and HRUBKA BETWEEN " + sklad_od + " AND " + sklad_do) : "") +
         " ", cn))
```

Otherwise :

```
using (SqlDataAdapter dr = new SqlDataAdapter(" select * from tab_sklad "
        "where SMENA LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_smena_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (txt_smena_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " and DATUM LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_datum_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (txt_datum_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " and DODAVATEL LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_firma_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (cmb_firma_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " and CISLO_PALETY LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_paleta_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (txt_paleta_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " and HRUBKA LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_hrubka_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (txt_hrubka_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " and KVALITA LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_kvalita_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (cmb_kvalita_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") + 
         " and DRUH LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmb_druh_sklad_filter.Text) ? "'" : (cmb_druh_sklad_filter.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " and HRUBKA LIKE '%" + String.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_sklad_do.Text) ? "'" : (txt_sklad_do.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "%'") +
         " ", cn))
```

Comment: I added images.